# DSUM with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the sum of all items in column `F:F` when Column `J:J = "Channel"`and Column `K:K = "Country"`

```
=DSUM(Sheet1!$A$1:$K$142,Sheet1!$F$2:$F$142,{{Sheet1!K:K;"Channel"},{Sheet1!L:L;"Country"}})
```

The above query returns a 0 when it should return a 7.

Comment: I've added a section "N5:O6" with my criteria and this seems to work, I'd like to include this formula right in my sheet without the new range.
"=DSUM(F1:K126,1,N5:O6)"

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
=DSUM(Sheet1!$A$1:$L$142, Sheet1!$F$1, {{Sheet1!$K$1; "Channel"}, {Sheet1!$L$1; "Country"}})
```

Notice changes about the parameters:

1. `Sheet1!$A$1:$L$142` column `L:L` should be included if you want to use it in your criteria.
2. Second parameter just needs a column name (`Sheet1!$F$1`) or its number (6). No need to place the whole range there.
3. You need to have a two strings range for criteria: first one with the column name, second with the criteria for that column. You set before the whole column `K:K` and `L:L` and placed a string to match at the bottom. Only the first tow rows were used, so you criteria was actually like this: kolumn `K:K` should be like the value in `K2` and column `L:L` like the value in `L2` (but this one didn't actually worked as this column was not a part of your table (the 1st parameter)).

Or you can use [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en&authuser=0):

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$142, Sheet1!$K$2:$K$142, "Channel", Sheet1!$L$2:$L$142, "Country")
```

Or if you need to sum the whole column (not just down to 142 row):

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$F:$F, Sheet1!$K:$K, "Channel", Sheet1!$L:$L, "Country")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic proof-of-concept.

**Count all vegetables**

- Answer: 18
- Formula: `=DSUM(A4:D10,"Qty",{"Category";"Vegetable"})`

**Count all vegetables at Safeway**

- Answer: 10
- Formula: `=DSUM(A4:D10,"Qty",{{"Category";"Vegetable"},{"Store";"Safeway"}})`

[image: DSUM Grocery Example]